# Paradox Brownian Motion : P(first passage time < infinite) = 1 yet E(first passage time) = infinite?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance

I am studying the bible of stochastic calculus for finance by Shreve aka God.

But in the section "first passage time to level m" for the Brownian Motion there is a paradox :
1)  P(first passage time < infinite) = 1
2)  E(first passage time) = infinite

For me it is a paradox. How can you be at the same time finite and infinite?

Is there a solution or a interpretation to solve the paradox ?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a paradox: tons of random variables are 1. almost surely finite, and 2. not integrable. For a similar situation with no alea, consider $f(x)=1/x$ on $x>1$, then $f(x)$ is finite for every $x>1$ "but" $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ is infinite.

Comment: Take pdf $1/x^2$ in $[1,\infty)$.  Find the expected value.